# How to handle a fork that follows upstream in Git/Mercurial?

Tags: git, mercurial, dvcs

We've forked a huge project, since we want to offer a modified version of it. We absolutely intend to keep following upstream, rebasing our changes on top of it whenever they release a new stable version.

However, I'm not sure how to best handle that when it comes to version control. Here's what we did to get started (I don't mind if the answer talks about Git or Mercurial, since I'm familiar with both, but I'll talk Git here.):

1. Clone the upstream project
2. Create a new branch named like our product, let's say `foo`, on top of `master`.
3. Commit all our changes in the `foo` branch.

(I believe that's called a "vendor branch".)

Now we have to get the latest upstream changes in. The first step would naturally be to pull the upstream changes into `master`, which we didn't touch so far. But what then?

What I'd really like to do is rebase `foo` on top of `master`. However, since we already pushed the `foo` branch to our repository and are collaborating on it, `git push --force` doesn't seem like an option.

I see two alternatives:

1. Merge `master` into `foo`.
2. Create a new vendor branch based on `master`, merge all changes from the old one into that one.

Both don't seem ideal:

1. The history of `foo` will end up being intertwined with `master`,  rather than being isolated from it. And when there's a merge conflict, we'll have to modify the upstream commits, rather than our own, during merge.
2. I suppose this'd work just as desired. However, creating a new branch for each new version seems like a hack, people will always have to check they're on the right one...

Is there another option? What's the best way to do this in Git or Mercurial?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how extensive your changes are and are going to become.

I'll talk mercurial as I'm far more familiar with that:

If it's only a small set of patches applied on top of upstream default branch, then you can rebase your patch series / changesets always on top of upstream tip when you pulled in their changes. The evolve extension might come in handy in this scenario.

Alternatively, and possibly preferentially (I don't quite see why the merge approach should be problematic): it depends on which head you merge and which you use as your base: commit your changes. Then pull upstream. Update to upstream tip and merge the head which contains your local changes. Then you need to make modifications only to your changed head - not to upstream commits. Use bookmarks to distinguish the (anonymous) heads which are both part of default branch.